# CSS absolute positioning, box-shadow and overflow auto

Tags: html, css, overflow, shadow, absolute

I have an absolute positioned wrapper div that is containing my menu elements.

The wrapper element is positioned directly at the top and the bottom of the viewport, so its height is always 100% of the browser window.

The menu elements inside the wrapper element have a box-shadow which is overflowing the wrapper at the right side. Usually this is not a problem and the shadow is still visible.

However, I need to make the wrapper scrollable in case the menu elements inside are higher than the wrapper itself. But adding `overflow-y: auto` will cut the shadow of the menu at the right side (whether a scrollbar is visible or not).

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <div id="main">Main</div>
        <div id="sub">Sub</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:250px;
    background-color:#eee;
    overflow-y:auto;
}

#menu {
    position:relative;  
    box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

#main {
    height:200px;
    background-color:green;
    padding:5px;
}

#sub {
    height:100px;
    background-color:orange;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Please check this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Kc9Zk/

How can I make the shadow visible if there is no scrollbar?

Please note that I do not want to make the wrapper wider than the elements inside because the scrollbar would look somewhat misplaced if visible.

Comment: try increasing the wrapper divs width

Answer (score 2):

One solution to this is to make the wrapper wider than the elements by using positive spacing (padding). If you add padding to the wrapper, you can make it wider whilst still hiding the scroll bar.

```
#wrapper{
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

---

I'll make a fiddle when I'm not on my phone.